# Angular ng-content: how to use parents data as children input

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have a component that uses `<ng-content></ng-content>`, and this component has itself some data that should be passed to whatever component goes inside the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tags.

**Component that uses ngContent:**

*parent.component.ts*

```
class ParentComponent {
    data;
}
```

*parent.component.html*

```
<p>Data:</p>
<ng-content><ng-content>
```

**Component that should go inside Component that uses ngContent:**

*child.component.ts*

```
class ChildComponent {
    // I need this to be passed from parent component
    @Input() data; 
}
```

*child.component.html*

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let element of data">{{ element.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

**Desired usage:**

*view.component.html*

```
<parent-component>
    <child-component [data]="data"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Is there a way to have the `child-component`'s input `[data]` come from `parent-component`? I have tried this approach in a personal project, but I get an empty list, somehow is not been passed.

Comment: What have you tried? Will `<parent-component #parent>
    <child-component [data]="parent.data">` work for you?

Comment: @yurzui I tried what you can see on the question post, I will give a look at what you propose.

Comment: @yurzui I could try it and worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution closest to your desired usage would be achieved through the use of [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars):

```
<parent-component #parent>
  <child-component [data]="parent.data"></child-component>
</parent-component>
```